# Python i18n using pygettext.py

Tags: python, internationalization

I am starting on localisation, but I get stuck.

1. The program

   ```
   #example.py
   import gettext
   t = gettext.translation('cn', 'C:\locale', fallback=True)
   _ = t.ugettext 
   print _('Hello!')
   ```

   does work.
2. But when try to use pygettext

   ```
   python pygettext.py -d cn -o cn.pot example.py
   ```

   I get the message `"invalid syntax:<string>, line 1, pos 18`

I tried even the most simple pygettest command :

```
python pygettext.py example.py
```

which returns the same error.
I have tried with different other settings and changes in the program, but this error keeps returning.

The complete example I used the code from is http://achilles-keep-moving.blogspot.nl/2011/07/minimal-tutorial-for-python.html

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the `\` character in the string like `'C:\\foo.bar'` or  `r'C:\foo.bar'`.